# Low-resolution display in drop-down menu with huge characters in it

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu allowing the user to choose a font size, and 
each size is displayed "live" in the very size which it represents.

My code works fine, but unfortunately the initial display  of the closed menu is not good, 
it looks blurred and "low-resolution" (see picture below). How can I fix this ?

[image]

My code :

```css
    option.option1 {
     font-size:10px;
    }
    option.option2 {
     font-size:15px;
    }
    option.option3 {
     font-size:20px;
    }
    option.option4 {
     font-size:25px;
    }
    option.option5 {
     font-size:30px;
    }
    option.option6 {
     font-size:35px;
    }
    option.option7 {
     font-size:40px;
    }
    option.option8 {
     font-size:45px;
    }
    option.option9 {
     font-size:50px;
    }
    option.option10 {
     font-size:55px;
    }
    option.option11 {
     font-size:60px;
    }
```

```html
    <select id="font_size" > 
    <option value="0" selected> Choose font size </option>
    <option value="1" class="option1">  Size 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="option2">  Size 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="option3">  Size 3</option>
    <option value="4" class="option4">  Size 4</option>
    <option value="5" class="option5">  Size 5</option>
    <option value="6" class="option6">  Size 6</option>
    <option value="7" class="option7">  Size 7</option>
    <option value="8" class="option8">  Size 8</option>
    <option value="9" class="option9">  Size 9</option>
    <option value="10" class="option10">  Size 10</option>
    <option value="11" class="option11">  Size 11</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: what css are you using on making that box? don't see any css/markup relevant to it

Comment: In what browser do you see that result? I see different results in IE, Firefox and Chrome on Windows...

Comment: @RichardEverett In Firefox 35.0 on my Mac 10.8.5. Thanks for your editing, by the way. It displays OK in your browser?

Comment: On Windows: In IE 11 I see a normal-sized dropdown, with options that have different font sizes. In Chrome I just see a normal-sized dropdown with normal-sized options. In Firefox I see dropdown that is vertically sized to allow for the largest option, with options that have different font sizes but when you select an option it gets shown in the collapsed dropdown at normal size. If you're looking for a cross-browser solution you might need to roll your own...